# How to get iframe src value dynamically in nightwatch test case?

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, nightwatch.js

My html dom includes a  tag and the value of the src is dynamically generated. Please see below screenshot as an example:

[image]

I want to test the dom under the selected iframe tag:

```
<iframe class="ide-page-frame" ng-src="http://localhost:8080/che/wksp-rn6c?uid=514006" src="http://localhost:8080/che/wksp-rn6c?uid=514006"></iframe>
```

I use below method to load the frame and put the assert code in the callback function. But it doesn't find any dom. The code is shown as below.

```
browser
  .url('http://localhost:8080/dashboard/#/ide/che/wksp-rn6c')
  .frame(".ide-page-frame",()=>{
        // it can't find any dom here
     })
   })
```

If I load the dynamical url `http://localhost:8080/che/wksp-rn6c?uid=514006` directly, it is able to find the dom elements. So I want to know how I can get the url from the iframe src in the test case. Does nightwatch support something like `$(.ide-page-frame).getAttribute('src')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is in **browser.iframe(".ide-page-frame")**

- nightwatch will look for an iFrame having the *id="ide-page-frame"* which does not exist in your page.

> If the frame id is missing or null, the server should switch to the
>   page's default content.

My proposition: Please change your iFrame creation by changing **class="ide-page-frame"** by **id="ide-page-frame"** (or you can just add the *id* and keep the *class*)

```
<iframe id="ide-page-frame" class="ide-page-frame" ng-src="http://localhost:8080/che/wksp-rn6c?uid=514006" src="http://localhost:8080/che/wksp-rn6c?uid=514006"></iframe>
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Is '.ide-page-frame' a class selector or id selector?

Comment: @ZhaoYi When you have an iframe element like <iframe id="idIframe"> you change focus to it using client.frame('idIframe') so in your case it should be browser.frame("ide-page-frame")